# Parents Whose Last Created Child is a 'Failure'

Tags: soql, lookup, parent

I have a lookup relation, so I need to filter Parents (id, Name) whose last created Child has status__c Failure.

Tried something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Parent
WHERE RecordType.Name = 'rt'
AND Id IN (
  SELECT Parent__c
  FROM Child__c
  WHERE Status__c = 'Failure'
  /*ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 1*/
```

But I cannot find a way to filter only Parents based on the condition, since you cannot use an ORDER BY in a subquery

Comment: You will need some additional processing. You can't do what you want with pure soql.

Comment: @AdrianLarson please check my ans

Comment: For a brief moment when I saw this on the hot network questions I thought it was a badly worded question on [parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think some schools would be very interested in potential answers to this question.  Upvoted for hilarious, unintentional misunderstanding

Comment: I was so focused on the context, that I really, really didn't notice the ugly title! But Thank you guys, your help was useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Adrian noted in the comments on your question, this isn't possible to achieve via SOQL alone.

While you can't use `ORDER BY` in a semi-join/Left Inner Join (i.e. a subquery appearing in the `WHERE`), you can use `ORDER BY` in a Left Outer Join (a.k.a. a parent-child subquery, one that appears in the `SELECT` clause).

I can't find documentation that corroborates that last statement, but I have the next best thing, code that anyone can run to prove it for themselves. If you feel the need, just run the following as anonymous apex:

```
for(Account a :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account LIMIT 10]){
    system.debug(a.Id + ': ' + a.Opportunities);
}
```

Given that the above works, an approach that I might suggest would be to use a Left Outer Join to find the 'last created child' (which I take to mean the most recently created child), and then use apex to figure out whether or not that child record's status is 'Failure'

```
Set<Id> latestChildFailureParentIds = new Set<Id>();

// If you want to find the oldest child record, simply replace 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC'
//   with 'ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC'
for(Parent p :[SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Status FROM Children ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Parent WHERE recordType.Name = 'rt']){
    if(!p.Children.isEmpty() && p.Children[0].Status == 'Failure'){
        latestChildFailureParentIds.add(p.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, order doesn't matter for the filter join, but sure can for results. I do believe it's documented. Will be tough to find on mobile though.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try out like this where Subquery has been replaced by INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Parent__c, Parent__r.Name, COUNT(Id), MAX (CreatedDate)
FROM Child__c 
WHERE Status__c = 'Failure' AND Parent__r.RecordType.Name = 'rt'
GROUP BY Parent__c,Parent__r.Name
ORDER BY Parent__c, Parent__r.Name LIMIT 100
```

I have tested this at my org.

It will show latest Child created date with status = 'Failure'. Also, for a parent single Child record will be filtered. For this reason, `COUNT(Id)` and `Max(CreatedDate)` comes into play.

Comment: it is possible in SOQL, please run this at your org

Comment: This query does not tell you if the most recent child has the specified status.

Comment: Max (CreatedDate) will give you

Comment: That just tells you the date of the most recent failure. You get some useful information, but I think there's some missing nuance with this approach.

Comment: I had assumed, the records has been created with failure status

Comment: @Adrian Larson You are correct. The `MAX(CreatedDate)` is kind of misleading. So I went and tried this query in my org and here are the results : http://imgur.com/a/WtJeF @Santanu Boral you need to change the query.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't help you with historical data, but I would set up a flow using `Process Builder` to update a `Most Recent Child Status` field (or a lookup to that child record). Make sure to have it fire only on record creation.

Once it's populated, just filter on this field. For example, if you use a relationship, include this clause:

```
WHERE Most_Recent_Child__r.Status__c = 'Failure'
```

A batch to backfill wouldn't be too much work, for the historical aspect.

**Query (`start`)**

```
SELECT (
    SELECT Status__c FROM Children__r
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
) FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Parent__c FROM Child __c
)
```

**Logic (`execute`)**

```
for (Parent__c parent : scope) 
    parent.Most_Recent_Child__c = parent.Children__r[0].Id;
update scope;
```